# Getting [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED] error while trying to generate a jhipster application

Tags: npm, jhipster, yarnpkg

So, I was trying to generate a new jhipster application (for the first time) and while the packages downloaded without any problems, while I tried to generate a jhipster application I got this error

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/util/namespace' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\user\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-environment\package.json
.
.
.
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\scoop\persist\nodejs\bin\node_modules\generator-jhipster\utils\blueprint.js:19:25) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
```

I tried to reinstall the packages both locally and globally but the result remains the same.

Comment: Use Node 16 and everything should work.